# I lost a device's power adapter, what should i seek for a new power adapter?

Tags: voltage, power, led, lamp, consumer

i bought an expensive desk lamp from the US called [Lumiy Lightsblade 1500s](https://lumiy.com/index.php/led-desk-lamps-stunning-lighting/lightblade-series-office-led-desk-lamps/lightblade-1500s-black), i lost the power adapter, so my questions are as you are electrical engineers:
1) can i use it in israel [(The standard voltage is 230 V and the standard frequency is 50 Hz.)](https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/israel/) ? does it lose its peak because the countries difference?
2) what power adapter should i seek for when buying?

[image: Power supply]
[image: Table from the website of lumiy]

Comment: 12V DC 2A, as it says on the label, but make sure the new adapter has the correct plug. Easiest way would be to buy a replacement from teh manufacturer.

Comment: If you lost the power adapter..... you can't use it anywhere. If you are seeking product recommendations for a replacement, that subject is normally off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in your country.

Specs allow you to use any power adapter which outputs 12 VDC and can supply 2 A or more current. You need to buy a correct plug that can work with your light.